# How to update pubspec.yaml on flutter pub upgrade automatically?

Tags: flutter

Coming from npm, I deeply dislike the way Google handles package updates within Flutter. Instead of updating the pubspec.yaml on `flutter pub upgrade`, it will only update the pubspec.lock.

To ensure that the pubspec.yaml is up to date, I have to run `flutter pub outdated` and manually adjust the pubspec.yaml before running `flutter pub upgrade`. I'm too lazy for that, it's no fun, I want this to be automated. The recommend versions of `flutter pub outdated` should be set in the pubspec.yaml for me.

How to I do that?

Comment: If you'd prefer to not have versioning and to always get the latest package version when doing `flutter pub upgrade`, you can remove the version constraints from `pubspec.yaml` entirely.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Ctrl+Space after a package name in pubspec.yaml to get the latest version.

> you must press Ctrl+Space exactly one space after ' : ' to see the latest version.

```
cupertino_icons: <click Ctrl+Space here>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not respect the previous value that has a caret to indicate that major updates are not preferred. It's nice to get the latest version, but if there is a newer major version I cannot use this solution to get the latest minor/build version. Some suggestions also seem to not work. Very unreliable and still inconvenient, especially when I have a lot of packages. Still handy to know about.

Comment: So it seems on closer inspection I can see that Flutter will actually suggest two values if the latest is not compatible. This is the highest version that is prefixed with a `*` on `flutter pub outdated`. Can this resolvable version really be used without problems? I would expect a major update to be not compatible, but Flutter claims otherwise.